# How to get the sum of two defined variables in Jinja2 ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have 04 server packs. Those are downloaded and extracted in a loop. I want to change the port numbers as 4000,4001,4002,4003 and 40004.

I have defined the variables in `roles/myrole/vars/main.yml` as follow

```
port: 4000
node:4
item:4
```

In my `roles/myrole/tasks/main.yml`, I have defined the tasks

```
- name: Change axis2 configs
  template:
    src: ~/myproject/roles/myrole/templates/axis2.xml.j2
    dest: ~/myproject/{{ item }}/sever/axis2/axis2.xml
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{ node }}
```

In the axis2 template I have added the variable as;

```
<parameter name="localMemberPort">{{ port }}</parameter>
{% set port = port + 1 %}
```

But I when I run the playbook, still the ports are replaced with 4000. How to do this task or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `roles/myrole/vars/main.yml` as follows

```
port: 4000
node: 4
```

You don't need to specify item, because item is the current sequence number

And if you would like you can write a direct count in your task

```
- name: Change axis2 configs
  template:
    src: ~/myproject/roles/myrole/templates/axis2.xml.j2
    dest: ~/myproject/{{ item }}/sever/axis2/axis2.xml
  with_sequence: count={{ node }}
```

Just change your axis2 template to

```
<parameter name="localMemberPort">{{ port|int + item|int }}</parameter>
```

You don't need to set a variable in your logic for this purpose.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `{% set ... %}` command only sets variables within the context of the template. It has no effect on subsequent iterations of the task.  Since you're iterating using `with_sequence`, you can just add your loop variable to `port` like this:

```
<parameter name="localMemberPort">{{ port|int + item|int }}</parameter>
```

For example, the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    node: 4
    port: 4000
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          <parameter name="localMemberPort">{{ port|int + item|int }}</parameter>
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{ node }}
```

Produces as output:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => {
    "msg": "<parameter name=\"localMemberPort\">4000</parameter>"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": "<parameter name=\"localMemberPort\">4001</parameter>"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "<parameter name=\"localMemberPort\">4002</parameter>"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => {
    "msg": "<parameter name=\"localMemberPort\">4003</parameter>"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) => {
    "msg": "<parameter name=\"localMemberPort\">4004</parameter>"
}
```

---

Incidentally, I hope you're not actually setting `item` in `roles/myrole/vars/main.yml`: this is the default loop variable name, and attempting to set it in a vars file like this is just going to cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in looping through a list **and** using the index value of each list item this what I did:

```
- name: "Install supervisord template for {{ role }} and notify supervisor of the change"
  template: 
    src: "supervisord.conf.j2"
    dest: "{{ supervisor_conf_dir }}/{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}.conf"
    owner: "{{ deploy_user }}"
    group: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  with_indexed_items:
    - "{{ the_endpoints }}"
  notify:
    - "add_{{ role }}"
    - "update_{{ role }}"
  tags:
    - "additional_templates"
    - "supervisor_configs"
```

debug of this gives output where index.0 is the index value and index.1 is the item from the list:

item=(1, u'm19')

and use it in a template such as:

```
[program:{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}]
autorestart = true
autostart = true
command = {{ opskit_dir }}/{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}/bin/prometheus --web.external-url='https://{{ inventory_hostname }}:4434/{{ deploy_env }}-{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}' --config.file='{{ opskit_dir }}/{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}/conf/{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}.yml' --storage.tsdb.path='{{ deploy_dir }}/data/{{ role }}
_{{ item.1 }}/data' --storage.tsdb.retention='365d' --log.level='debug' --web.listen-address=':{{ prometheus_internal_port|int + item.0|int }}'
directory = {{ opskit_dir }}/{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = {{ opskit_dir }}/log/{{ role }}_{{ item.1 }}.log
stdout_logfile_backups = 5
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stopwaitsecs = 300
```